# Как сделать чтоб это заработало?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему вот так работает

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.good_arrow').click(function() {
    $('.fulldisc').slideToggle('slow');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="good">
  <div class="good_wrap">
    <div class="good_discription">
      <div class="good_logo">
        <img src="foto_product/small/cat1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="good_country">
        <p>Greiner Bio-one (Австрия)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="good_article">
        <p>455092</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="good_main">
      <div class="good_img">
        <img src="foto_products/small/172.jpg?=231798872">
      </div>
      <div class="good_name">
        <h3>GDM-92</h3>
        <h4>Пробирки ваккумные (455092)"VACUETTE" для сыворотки 9 мл 16*100 мм, без резьбы</h4>
        <p>Диаметр: 0.00</p>
        <p>Объём (V) барабана: 0.7 см3</p>
        <p>Размер крошки: 0,9-1,0 мм</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="good_price">
      <div class="good_check">
        <img src="images/check.png">
      </div>
      <div class="gprice">
        <p>1200<span>р</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="good_delivery">
        <p>Доставка за 1-2 дня</p>
      </div>
      <div class="addcart">
        <div class="add">
          <div class="num_good">
            <p>1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="button_good">
            <p>В корзину</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="good_arrow"><img src="images/arrow_blue.jpg" width="15" height="15"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fulldisc">
    <p>Пробирки ваккумные для забора крови 9 мл 16*100 мм, (без резьбы)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

А вот так не работает `slideToggle`???  (Ошибок нет)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.good_arrow').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.fulldisc').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="good">
  <div class="good_wrap">
    <div class="good_discription">
      <div class="good_logo">
        <img src="foto_product/small/cat1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="good_country">
        <p>Greiner Bio-one (Австрия)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="good_article">
        <p>455092</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="good_main">
      <div class="good_img">
        <img src="foto_products/small/172.jpg?=231798872">
      </div>
      <div class="good_name">
        <h3>GDM-92</h3>
        <h4>Пробирки ваккумные (455092)"VACUETTE" для сыворотки 9 мл 16*100 мм, без резьбы</h4>
        <p>Диаметр: 0.00</p>
        <p>Объём (V) барабана: 0.7 см3</p>
        <p>Размер крошки: 0,9-1,0 мм</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="good_price">
      <div class="good_check">
        <img src="images/check.png">
      </div>
      <div class="gprice">
        <p>1200<span>р</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="good_delivery">
        <p>Доставка за 1-2 дня</p>
      </div>
      <div class="addcart">
        <div class="add">
          <div class="num_good">
            <p>1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="button_good">
            <p>В корзину</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="good_arrow"><img src="images/arrow_blue.jpg" width="15" height="15"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fulldisc">
    <p>Пробирки ваккумные для забора крови 9 мл 16*100 мм, (без резьбы)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вроде как должно быт очевидно, что `.fulldisc` не  является дочерним узлом `.good-wrapper`, к которому вы обращаетесь через `parent()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у .good_arrow и .fulldisc разные родители. Вам надо подняться на уровень выше. Используете `$(this).parents('.good')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.good_arrow').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.good').find('.fulldisc').slideToggle('slow');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="good">
  <div class="good_wrap">
    <div class="good_discription">
      <div class="good_logo">
        <img src="foto_product/small/cat1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="good_country">
        <p>Greiner Bio-one (Австрия)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="good_article">
        <p>455092</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="good_main">
      <div class="good_img">
        <img src="foto_products/small/172.jpg?=231798872">
      </div>
      <div class="good_name">
        <h3>GDM-92</h3>
        <h4>Пробирки ваккумные (455092)"VACUETTE" для сыворотки 9 мл 16*100 мм, без резьбы</h4>
        <p>Диаметр: 0.00</p>
        <p>Объём (V) барабана: 0.7 см3</p>
        <p>Размер крошки: 0,9-1,0 мм</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="good_price">
      <div class="good_check">
        <img src="images/check.png">
      </div>
      <div class="gprice">
        <p>1200<span>р</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="good_delivery">
        <p>Доставка за 1-2 дня</p>
      </div>
      <div class="addcart">
        <div class="add">
          <div class="num_good">
            <p>1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="button_good">
            <p>В корзину</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="good_arrow">CLICK HERE<img src="images/arrow_blue.jpg" width="15" height="15"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fulldisc">
    <p>Пробирки ваккумные для забора крови 9 мл 16*100 мм, (без резьбы)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "parents" по производительности хуже, чем "closest", потому первый ответ лучше, да и правильнее в данном контексте.

Answer (score 4):

Вы указываете некорректный путь к элементу. `parent()` указывает на класс `good_wrap`, который не является родителем для `.fulldisc`

```
$(this).closest('.good').find('.fulldisc').slideToggle();
```